# If string is found in range 'Yes' else 'No'

Tags: string, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, wildcard

I think I am almost there, I have this formula:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("READONLY";D17:P17;0));"FOUND";"NOT FOUND")`

I would like to search for the text `READONLY`. So if `READONLY` is found then FOUND else NOT FOUND. Please note that the cells that contain `READONLY` also contain other text, for example: `fsdfsdfssfs READONLY`.

Comment: Result so far is just 0 - not even FOUND or NOT FOUND

Comment: How is your data structured? The solutions below should work, barring something in the data type, or structure, being different than expected.

Comment: Made a mistake in the range: I also included the formula cell itself.. thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *wildcard* the criteria in the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*READONLY*"; D17:P17; 0));"FOUND";"NOT FOUND")
```

Another option is the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34).

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D17:P17; "*READONLY*");"FOUND";"NOT FOUND")
```

[image: Wildcard match]

Comment: Found the mistake: I had the formula cell itself also in the range. So in your example I had the range B17:P17 instead of D17:P17 - Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad to hear you got sorted out! Thanks for clearing up the anomaly.

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
"*READONLY*"
```

instead of

```
"READONLY"
```

Comment: I found my mistake, please see comment on the answer from Jeeped. - I can not mark both answers as correct? since both are answers are correct in my opinion?